# Mysql returns array string but want in numbers

Tags: mysql

I have table like this with two rows

```
UID  & ids

1   & 2.3
2   & 5
3   &   4
4   &  1.2
```

etc
I write a query with gruop_concat()

Query is

```
select *
from tbltable
where tableId Not In(
    SELECT tableId
    FROM `tblbooking`
    where restaurantid = 1
        and date(starttime) = date(p_starttime)
        and Time(StartTime) >= Time(p_starttime)
        And Time(EndTime) <= Time(p_endtime)
    )
    and NoOfSeats >= p_noofseats
```

It returns "2,3,4,5,1,2" But i want  comma separated values not a String Like 2,3,4,5,1,2

Comment: Are you running this query using some programming language? Or are you running it straight from a MySQL console/interface?

Comment: "2,3,4,5,1,2" looks like comma separated values to me

Comment: Your example doesn't use `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Comment: @OP: Any of *`concat`* functions return a *string* only.

Comment: i am using from MySQL console. i need data as integer because its use in another query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Is Exact thing with substring

SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(maintable.choices,',',othertable.id),',',-1) AS choice
FROM maintable INNER JOIN othertable ON
    (LENGTH(choices)>0 AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(choices,',',othertable.id),',',-1)
    <> SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(choices,',',othertable.id-1),',', -1));

Please check this link
http://www.tero.co.uk/scripts/mysql.php

Thanks .